# mysqldump command fails in Laravel command

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a Laravel command that backs up the MySQL database daily.

This is the command:

```
/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->process = new Process([sprintf(
        "mysqldump -u%s -p'%s' %s > %s",
        config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
        storage_path('app/public/backups/backup.sql')
    )]);
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle()
{
    try {
        $this->process->mustRun();

        $this->info('The database has been backed up successfully.');
    } catch (ProcessFailedException $exception) {
        logger()->debug($exception->getMessage());
        $this->error('The backup process has failed.');
    }

}
```

When I check what command actually runs, I see this:

```
/Users/jovan/path_to_project/mysqldump -uuser -p'passpass' project > /Users/jovan/path_to_project/storage/app/public/backups/backup.sql
```

It doesn't work because, for some reason, it creates an absolute path for the `mysqldump` command (`/Users/jovan/path_to_project/mysqldump`).

When I change the command to the following and run it manually, it works alright:

```
mysqldump -uuser -p'passpass' project > /Users/jovan/path_to_project/storage/app/public/backups/backup.sql
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use this instead https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using path for mysqldump that is not executable.

First, try to locate the `mysqldump` executable by performing: `which mysqldump` and then add the output (absolute path) to your CLI command content.

```php
    $this->process = new Process([sprintf(
        "mysqldump -u%s -p'%s' %s > %s",
        config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
        storage_path('app/public/backups/backup.sql')
    )]);
```

into

```php
    $this->process = new Process([sprintf(
        "/absolute/path/to/mysqldump -u%s -p'%s' %s > %s",
        config('database.connections.mysql.username'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.password'),
        config('database.connections.mysql.database'),
        storage_path('app/public/backups/backup.sql')
    )]);
```

Comment: OK but this used to work the way I had it. Why would it not just try to run it as I typed it?

Comment: please take a look at the process compontent: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#using-features-from-the-os-shell

basically, it does not use features provided by your shell
also, take a look at the https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html#finding-an-executable

Comment: I did this and it still doesn't work. Only works when I manually change the command to just say `mysqldump` instead of `/usr/bin/mysqldump` (this is what I got from `which mysqldump`).